# Why feet don't rotate with root bone?

Tags: animation

Can anyone tell me why the feet of my model don't rotate with the root bone?
Below is a screenshot.
Thank you for taking the time.
Regards,
Bridie.[image]

Comment: This could be a number of things, especially because of how complicated this rig looks. How did you make the rig?

Comment: Looks like the rigify rig

Comment: Have you checked the weight-painting on the foot?

Comment: @zargulTheWizard.... I made the rig with rigiify plus I added bones for the eyes. how does the rig look complicated?  Sorry im new to blender. Thank you for taking the time to comment.

Comment: @NascentSpace.   Yes its the rigidify rig.  :) Thanks.

Comment: @SilverRain   thank you, yes I just checked the weight paint and it all seems fine.

Comment: In my experience: rigify rigs have tended to have multiple layers, and it’s been difficult for me to tell what is connected to watch.

Comment: @NascentSpace.   you said this could be a number of things. would you be able to name them, so that would give me some direction.... its hard to find anything online.

Comment: just make sure the parents are correct, also try testing with a new rigify and don't change anything just test if the feet move.

Comment: @NascentSpace. thanks for the tips. I tried the model with a new rigidify and it works fine. will use that. kind regards.